# Restore replica count message in netstats

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am not pretty clear about the restore replica count problem that is displayed in netstats. I get the following message in nodetool netstats output

Restore Replica Count xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Restore Replica Count YYYYYYYYYY-yyyyyyyyyy-yyyyyyyyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyy

I did a nodetool removenode on the same group in which the following node exists. Post that , this seems to be coming. Even if i run repair,the problem doesnt get resolved!!

Any pointers on what has to be done to resolve this. Moreover, the new node i have added doesnt own much of the data from this node. This node seems to hog the majority of the group data , even if i run cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a node from a cluster, Cassandra invokes the following piece of code

```
/**
 * Called when an endpoint is removed from the ring. This function checks
 * whether this node becomes responsible for new ranges as a
 * consequence and streams data if needed.
 *
 * This is rather ineffective, but it does not matter so much
 * since this is called very seldom
 *
 * @param endpoint the node that left
 */
private void restoreReplicaCount(InetAddress endpoint, final InetAddress notifyEndpoint)
```

It then determines which pieces of each keyspace it will be acquiring, and then initiates streaming to get the data for those ranges (basically, ensures that you keep RF copies of data, for all of the data that existed on the node that you removed).

It exposes those streams in **nodetool netstats** with the rest of the streaming plans, so you can see progress for those streams (separate from other streams that may be happening in your system, such as antientropy repair or bootstrapping streams).

Comment: But the following message is present for the past one week with no streaming happening. Any idea on that?